# How can I use multiple CookieAuthenticationOptions?

Tags: cookies, owin

I have 2 cookieAuthenticationoptions in my OWINStartup code, but only the first one is getting honored.

I cannot find any info. online on this, so will appreciate if someone can help me, if this is even possible. Here is my code:

```
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        // Enable clients to authenticate using cookies
        var cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "type1",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/"),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            Provider =
                    new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                    {
                        OnValidateIdentity = OnValidateIdentityAsync,
                        OnException = OnCookieException,
                        OnResponseSignIn = OnResponseSignIn,
                    },
        };

        // For auth tokens to properly work for both delve.office.com and <region>.delve.office.com
        // we use a separate auth cookie per region/deployment.
        if (!IsDevBox.Value)
        {
            cookieOptions.CookieName = AuthCookieNameWithoutSuffix + CookieHelper.GetCookieSuffix();
            cookieOptions.CookieDomain = AuthCookieDomain;
        }

        // Enable clients to authenticate using cookies
        var cookieOptions_BearerToken = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "type2",
            CookieName = "BearerToken",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/"),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            Provider =
                    new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                    {
                        OnValidateIdentity = OnValidateIdentityAsync_BearerToken,
                        OnException = OnCookieException,
                        OnResponseSignIn = OnResponseSignIn,
                    },
        };

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions_BearerToken);
```

If I just use the BearerToken option, it works - but in the above case it is not getting honored. Any ideas?

Thanks so much!